# Grunt JS - Helper for Ajax

Tags: ajax, gruntjs

i have a code like this

index.js

```
var content = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f'];
var $body = $(document.body);
var c = '';
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
   c += '<div>' + content[i] + '</div>';
}

$body.append(c);
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

can I automate this process? And Build a index.html with contents?

Comment: what you are trying to automate ?

Comment: i want to have a end html file with contents without javascript.